# Prove/Disprove: a clause $\exists xA$ is true in structure $M$ iff there is a term without FV such that $A\{\frac{t}{x}\}$ is true in $M$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Prove/Disprove: Let $M$ such that for every $a\in D$ (the domain) there's a term $t$ such that $t\mapsto a$,in $M$.
>   **Claim**: a clause $\exists xA$ is true in $M$ iff there is a term without free variables such that $A\{\frac{t}{x}\}$ (meaning, substitution of $x$ with $t$) is true in $M$.

My guess is that this claim isn't true, but a I cannot find a good example to demonstrate it.

I'd be glad for help!

Comment: What is a constant here?  Is it what is called a term by nearly everyone else?

Comment: I guess so. Let me change it

Comment: Preferably give its definition as given in your course/book.

Comment: What if the language has no terms? :) other than variables, that is.

Comment: Would the following work? Language: Single binary predicate symbol $\lt$. Structure: Natural numbers, usual interpretation of $\lt$. Sentence: $\exists x\forall y(\lnot (y\lt x))$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how is it a contradiction? If $A=\forall y(\lnot (y < x))$ then the substitution of $t=0$ would make $A$ true in $M$.

Comment: There is no variable-free term $t$ for which the substitution result holds, since there are no variable-free terms at all.

Comment: No, it can't be. The domain must not be empty and therefore there must be some $t$ for $a\in D$.

Comment: Domain not empty means that there is an "object" in the domain; a language with a *term* means that we have in the language a "name". We can have objects but no names for them ...